# The flashing blue dot (user location) won't move

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I'm having a problem with my maps. I have `showsUserLocation` set and have done `startUpdatingLocation()`. The flashing blue dot appears, but it never moves. If I close the screen and re-open, the blue dot is re-positioned at the new location, but it's just static on the map. The callback to `didUpdateLocations` is being called and I can pick up the current location and draw an accurate way finding line. I just can't get the blue dot to move with the user. It was my understanding that the blue dot moved "on it's own" as long as the location is updating. What did I miss?

Here's somewhat of an overview of the code:

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class AppointmentDetailViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstTime = true

    self.mapView?.delegate = self

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView!.showsUserLocation = true

        mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)

    } else {
        print("Location service disabled", terminator: "")
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    firstTime = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("Location updated...")

    if firstTime {
        if appointment == nil { return }

        firstTime = false

        var latitude:Double = 0
        var longitude:Double = 0

        if appointment.latitude != nil {
            latitude = (appointment.latitude! as NSString).doubleValue
        }

        if appointment.longitude != nil {
            longitude = (appointment.longitude! as NSString).doubleValue
        }

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = appointment.providerFirstName! + " " + appointment.providerLastName!
        annotation.subtitle = appointment.address1
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        //        mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)

        // Get directions and draw route line
        let point1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        let point2 = MKPointAnnotation()

        myLatitude  = (locations.first?.coordinate.latitude)!
        myLongitude = (locations.first?.coordinate.longitude)!

        print(myLatitude)
        print(myLongitude)

        locationLatitude = myLatitude
        locationLongitude = myLongitude

        point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLatitude, myLongitude)

        point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(point2)
        mapView.centerCoordinate = point2.coordinate
        mapView.delegate = self

        //Span of the map
        //        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(point2.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.7,0.7)), animated: true)

        let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        let markSource = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point1.coordinate.latitude, point1.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
        let markDestination = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point2.coordinate.latitude, point2.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

        directionsRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: markSource)
        directionsRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: markDestination)
        directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

        directions.calculate { (response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.myRoute = response!.routes[0] as MKRoute

                for step in self.myRoute!.steps {
                    print(step.instructions)
                }

                var regionRect = self.myRoute?.polyline.boundingMapRect

                let wPadding = regionRect!.size.width * 0.5
                let hPadding = regionRect!.size.height * 0.5

                //Add padding to the region
                regionRect!.size.width += wPadding
                regionRect!.size.height += hPadding

                //Center the region on the line
                regionRect!.origin.x -= wPadding / 2
                regionRect!.origin.y -= hPadding / 2

                self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(regionRect!), animated: true)
                self.mapView.add((self.myRoute?.polyline)!)

            } else {
                print("Error calculating directions")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you only process the very first call to `didUpdateLocations`, why do you expect any other updates?

Comment: @rmaddy, I’m trying to draw the directions line only once, thus the first time check. However, the location is still updating and I still want the blue dot to update. Do I have to “process” the blue dot?

Comment: You need to set the map's centerCoordinate on each location update.

Comment: I think he's talking about the map's `userLocation`, which *is* supposed to update automatically. In fact, it's [documented to do so](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation). That being said, it shouldn't be required, but what happens if you explicitly set your map's `userTrackingMode` to `.follow`?

Comment: @MichaelHulet, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Return nil in `mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:` method if annotation is `MKUserLocation` ?